# FLEX 3 and MS-ACCESS

Tags: apache-flex

How do I connect Flex3 to a MS Access 2007 local database? Could you provide some example code for a login page using username and password and validating it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using AIR on Windows, I believe you'd have to use NativeProcess to interact with the MS Access database driver.  I have never seen any example code posted by anyone that does this.  You would need to use at least AIR 3, and I'm not sure if that is compatible with Flex 3.

You might want to consider using the SQLLite implementation that Flex comes with.

However, what's the use case for a login to a local database?

Comment: So..What is the result finally??Can't I connect using mxml and action script code to MS access database..Are there any other possibilities?(This is a sample test project given to me..)SomeOne help me please.

Comment: You may want to advertise somewhere that accepts postings for small Flex jobs (such as maybe the Adobe Flex forums) for someone to write a connector for you that could be used from MXML.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time Flex does not connect directly to a database.  Instead you use either [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html), or [RemoteObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html), or [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) to connect to a remote service.  That service handles all the database interactions.

Many server side languages, such as ColdFusion, can use Access databases.  But, Access was not built for client server environments and I would recommend against to use it in such a situation.

Comment: She wasn't asking about client/server environment.  She's probably trying to migrate from something like Director that Adobe has killed. Not sure why she'd choose Flex as a replacement LOL.

Comment: She did specify local; I missed that.  Then, yeah, NativeProcess would be the recommended solution.